# Node.js: Easiest way to capture stdout into string variable

Tags: node.js, stream, console, global-variables, stdout

I have the following code:

```
const spawn = require("child_process").spawn;

const netStat = spawn('netstat', ['-nat']);
const grepPort = spawn('grep', ['3000']);
const grepStatus = spawn('grep', ['ESTABLISHED']);

console.log('Determining public ip\'s connected to port 3000');

// get port 3000 from netstat
netStat.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  grepPort.stdin.write(data);
  });

netStat.on('close', (code) => {
  if (code !== 0) {console.log(`netstat process exited with code ${code}`);}
  grepPort.stdin.end();
});

// get ESTABLISHED from port 3000
grepPort.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  grepStatus.stdin.write(data);
  });

grepPort.on('close', (code) => {
  grepStatus.stdin.end();
});

grepStatus.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(data.toString())
  // Store data.toString() to variable here
});
```

I am trying to capture the final data into a string where the comment is in the 3rd to last line.

I've looked into streams, buffer objects, etc and got nothing to work (maybe I was doing them wrong?) so I'm looking for a fresh solution that will work or a simple "its not possible".

EDIT:
Lets say the code is revised:

```
const spawn = require("child_process").spawn;
var port = 3000
console.log(`Determining public ip\'s connected to port ${port}`);

let output = '';

const proc = spawn('sh', [
  '-c',
  `netstat -nat | grep ${port}.*ESTABLISHED | awk '{print $5}' | grep -v .*${port}`
]);

proc.stdout.on('data', (chunk) => {
  output += chunk.toString();
});

proc.stderr.on('data', (chunk) => {
  console.log(chunk.toString());
});

proc.on('error', (err) => {
  console.error(err);
});

proc.on('exit', (code) => {
  console.log("Done");
});

console.log(output); // Should print output, no?
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 4):

You can append all data event chunks onto one single string and do something with it when the pipe ends like so:

```
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
const proc = spawn('netstat', ['-nat']);

let output = '';
proc.stdout.on('data', (chunk) => {
  output += chunk.toString();
});
proc.on('exit', () => {
  console.log(output);
});
```

`output` starts as an empty string and each time there is a `data` event (more than once, usually) you can append the data to that string until the whole process is `exit`ed. Once the process `exit`s, you will have the total `stdout` output.

Also for your script, it might be easier to use one single `spawn` call and the `sh` command to connect all of those together with unix pipes outside of node.js. That, combined with the above would look like this:

```
const spawn = require("child_process").spawn;

console.log('Determining public ip\'s connected to port 3000');

let output = '';

const proc = spawn('sh', [
  '-c',
  'netstat -nat | grep 3000 | grep ESTABLISHED'
]);

proc.stdout.on('data', (chunk) => {
  output += chunk.toString();
});

proc.stderr.on('data', (chunk) => {
  console.log(chunk.toString());
});

proc.on('error', (err) => {
  console.error(err);
});

proc.on('exit', (code) => {
  console.log(code);
  console.log(output);
});
```

And if you still want separate `spawn`s, it may be easier/helpful to use the built-in `.pipe` methods to connect them together:

```
const spawn = require("child_process").spawn;

console.log('Determining public ip\'s connected to port 3000');

let output = '';

const netStat = spawn('netstat', ['-nat']);
const grepPort = spawn('grep', ['3000']);
netStat.stdout.pipe(grepPort.stdin);
const grepStatus = spawn('grep', ['ESTABLISHED']);
grepPort.stdout.pipe(grepStatus.stdin);

grepPort.stdout.on('data', (chunk) => {
  output += chunk.toString();
});

netstat.stderr.on('data', (chunk) => {
  console.log(chunk.toString());
});

grepPort.on('error', (err) => {
  console.error(err);
});

grepPort.on('exit', (code) => {
  console.log(code);
  console.log(output);
});
```

I found this error-prone locally because the process may exit before the pipes can be connected (e.g. `grep` likes to be informed it should listen to `stdin` with something like `grep -f -` otherwise it exits with status code 1). Additionally, each pipe can have `stderr` `data` events that you should listen to. That's a to handle so all pipes together might be helpful.

The grep line *could* be simpler too if it worked on your system, `grep '3000.*ESTABLISHED'` instead of two grep invocations.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!, I much prefer your first solution as well! As for `output`, it seems to be declared globally so why must it be in the `proc.on('exit', ...` block in order to be able to print to the console, etc?

Comment: Ultimately I would like to store the variable globally for use in other functions - not just print to console

Comment: The `exit` event is the last event to fire. By the time that event fires, you can be sure that no more output will come from stdout. At that point you could call another function and use the entire output being sure that it is the complete output and not just partial output. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes that makes sense to me assuming I understand you correctly. Thus, my code revision under the EDIT of original question should print the output, correct?

Comment: It won't because node will run all of your code (including that last line) first, then (on the event loop) later a few `data` events will fire, and after that (on the event loop) later, the `exit` event will fire. The time between those events is variable. Because the `event` handlers are async and your `console.log` at the bottom is synchronous, the synchronous code gets executed first and the async event handlers many milliseconds later.

Comment: So is it possible to set up a listener of sorts for the incoming async data and then on data do logic?

Comment: You can put code in the `grepPort.on('exit', (code) => {` handler and use the data you collected in `output` in that code.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use exec as a promise.

```
const exec = require('util').promisify(require('child_process').exec);
const { stdout, stderr } = await exec('Write your command here');
console.log(stdout, stderr);
```